# C# Adding to a list from another Form

Tags: c#

I'm using C# (WPF) for a project in which I'm adding people to a list to be displayed on the first form (MainWindow); a button is clicked on MainWindow to open a new form (Window1) where they can add details about the person to add to the list (Name, age, etc.), I'm having trouble passing these data. Here's what I have:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public List<Patients> newPatientList = new List<Patients>();
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
    private void button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Window1 addPx = new Window1();
        addPx.Show(); 
    }
```

Then in Window1, when the button is clicked:

```
MainWindow newPxList = new MainWindow(); 

newPxList.newPatientList.Add(new Patients(lstname.Text, frstname.Text, age.Text, 
                                          rm.Text, "", status.SelectedItem.ToString()));
```

Then the window closes, but the list does not seem to be updated on the original form.

Comment: You are making a new instance of MainWindow. You need to get the same instance. You could pass it as a parameter to Window1 in the constructor.

Comment: this is the reason: ***new MainWindow();***  please check the @BWA Answer/Comment

Answer (score 3, accepted):

in Window1, you're making new instance of `MainWindow`, think of it like you're creating new, blank and hidden copy of `MainWindow`. Because of that, your original `MainWindow` stays the same.

What you need to do is to pass reference (let's say *link*) of `MainWindow` to `Window1`

To do that, you need to make following things:

make property `Main`,  in your `Window1` class, and change default constructor to get `MainWindow` reference as a parameter, like this:

```
public MainWindow Main { get; set; }

public Window1(MainWindow main)
{
    InitializeComponent();
    this.Main = main;
}
```

Now, you have to change constructor when you're showing `Window1`, like this:

```
Window1 addPx = new Window1(this);
addPx.Show();
```

Make public method in `MainWindow`, something like this:

```
public void AddNewPatient(string lastName, string FirstName, string age)
{
    //add new ListItem here
}
```

And, in `Window1` call that method when needed, on button click, like this:

```
Main.AddNewPatient(lstname.Text, frstname.Text, age.Text /*etc */);
```

Comment: Thank you, worked great. Thanks for the explanation as well

Answer (score 2):

In `OnClick` mathod in `Window1` you create new instance MainWindow and add new patient to this instance. After this method this instance of `MainWindow` is destroyed. You should pass reference to list as a parm of `Window1`.

Eg.

```
private void button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    Window1 addPx = new Window1(newPatientList);
    addPx.Show(); 
}
```

And in `Window1` insted

```
newPxList.newPatientList.Add(new Patients(lstname.Text, frstname.Text, age.Text, 
                                          rm.Text, "", status.SelectedItem.ToString()));
```

Something like this:

```
patientListFromMainWindow.Add(new Patients(lstname.Text, frstname.Text, age.Text, 
                                              rm.Text, "", status.SelectedItem.ToString()));
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to pass a reference of the list to the new window

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public List<Patients> newPatientList = new List<Patients>();

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
    private void button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Window1 addPx = new Window1(newPatientList);
        addPx.Show(); 
    }
}

public partial class Window1 : Window
{
    List<Patients> _patients;
    public Window1(List<Patients> patients)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        _patients = patients;
    }
    private void button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
    _patients.Add(new Patients(lstname.Text, frstname.Text, age.Text, 
                                        rm.Text, "", status.SelectedItem.ToString()));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Instead of passing in any additional arguments into the `Window1` constructor, you can make use of `ShowDialog()` method and just get newly created patient when dialog is closed.

```
private void button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    Window1 wnd1 = new Window1();
    bool? dialogResult = wnd1.ShowDialog();
    if ( dialogResult.HasValue && dialogResult.Value )
    {
        newPatientList.Add(wnd1.Patient);
    }
}
```

Now you can adjust `Window1` to hold up the result :

```
class Window1 : Window
{
    Patient _patient;
    public Patient Patient
    {
        get { return _patient; }
    }

    // rest of your code

    void button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        _patient = new Patients(lstname.Text, frstname.Text, age.Text, rm.Text, "", status.SelectedItem.ToString());
        DialogResult = true;
        Close();
    }
}
```